# How to log/trace any method call of object in java

Tags: java, methods, call, logging, trace

I need some thing like a Python decorator. I need to store some information, specifically the method called, its start time, its end time, and its arguments. I cannot import anything outside of Java 1.5 libraries. Is there some thing like what is available in Python?

Comment: Yeah, i know like i said, i cant import anything in this project beyound java default libraries.

Comment: I assume you also don't want to modify the code that you need to profile?

Comment: @MikeDaniels exact and i dont know all metohds in this class

Comment: Maybe if you told us your scenario(even if its slightly obfuscated) and what you are trying to accomplish this question could be a little more productive.

Comment: @nsfyn55 my accomplish this time is to create a "debug" version to put in production and see the real behavior of your code, some things strange and random is happen, and i like to see all steps (Ps.: Performance is not a issue now, even in production.)

Comment: The go to for this kind of this is typically log4j. If you can't put log4j on the path, I guess you could write your own or redirect standard out to a file and use System.out. Just pepper the relevant code with log statements and let it spin.

Answer (score 6):

Good tracing tool for Java is [BTrace](http://kenai.com/projects/btrace).

Answer (score 2):

You can try  some profiler using Java Management Extensions or java agent.

See http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/j2se15/#mnm

Answer (score 2):

Java Instrumentation?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html

Example:

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/24/add-logging-at-class-load-time-with-instrumentation.html

Comment: Yep, this is probably the way to go. Unfortunately it looks like waldecir is going to be stuck manually modifying bytecode since he/she can't import a library like ASM or Javassist. Oh well.

Comment: any example to how can i add pre/pos function to all functios with instrumentation ?

Comment: That's what that tutorial is for, "This article will show how to implement such a Java agent, which transparently will add entry and exit logging to all methods in all your classes with the standard Java Logging API." Here's the link again: http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/24/add-logging-at-class-load-time-with-instrumentation.html

Comment: @cschooley, That tutorial uses Javassist.

Comment: @Mike Daniels: we don't know if the requirements of "not importing anything" are compile-time or runtime. One could easily use Javassist to postprocess a compiled code in such way that it has no dependencies. So the proposition to use Javassist seems quite good.

Answer (score 0):

No, Python  decorators do not let you monitor all the code without changing anything. You still have to put your decorator everywhere (and - essentially - wrap each of your functions into a function that does the counting).

I am not sure if I understand your requirements (you do not say if you need the code for production or testing; also, the requirement "not to import anything" is bizarre: are all your classes in the default package? are you allowed to use an IDE and a compiler?), but I think the simplest way would be to use Javassist (the second link kindly provided by cschooley is a perfect introduction), but do not use the agent: instead use CtClass#write() to instrument class files and save them to disk (possibly in a custom ant task). This way the final build will not need any special set-up.

Comment: Yeah ython dont do this, i need a way to add a decorator behaviour in all methods of a class to extract some informations.

Comment: @waldecir: you already got the answers, why don't you use them?

Answer (score 0):

You might get away with a Java `Proxy` class if you can rely on interface methods only.

Answer (score 0):

[`@Loggable`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/annotation-loggable.html) annotation and an AspectJ aspect from [jcabi-aspects](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/) may help you. Annotate all your methods and every time they are being called SLF4J will receive log messages:

```
@Loggable(Loggable.DEBUG)
public String load(URL url) {
  return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```

In the next versions of `jcabi-aspects` a full logging of a class will be implemented: https://github.com/yegor256/jcabi/issues/129